# how to reduce the dictionary and same time do computation with numeric value?

Tags: python

I want to convert this dictionary:

```
d1 = {'course ': 'python', 'LastGPA' : 90, 'CurrentGPA': 80}
```

Into this:

```
d1 = {'course ': 'python', 'LastGPA+CurrentGPA' : (90+80)/2}
```

That is average of last two numbers in Python.

Comment: What do you mean with the " average of last two numbers "? Python dictionaries keys are unordered. How are you getting the input?

Comment: is your dict just an example or is constant ? or you want the average of all int values in any dict? or you want the average of last 2 values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following way

```
def new_dic(d1):
    x=[]
    y=[]
    x1=[]
    for item in d1:
        x.append(item)
        y.append(d1[item])

    for value in y:
        try:
            x1.append(int(value))
        except ValueError:
            continue
    x2 = x[-2]+'+'+x[-1]
    d1.update({x2:sum(x1)/len(x1)})
    d1.pop(x[-2])
    d1.pop(x[-1])
    print(d1)

new_dic(d1)
```